# How to initialize the bitmap array in android?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am novice in android development.I am developing a game.It has 20 images with image names like num1,num2,num3..,num20.

For reading all these images i have done this in java

```
for ( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
imgarr[i] = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage( this.getClass().getResource("images/"+(i+1)+".png"));
}
```

My question is how to do the same in android?

How to read all those images into bitmap array in simple for loop?

I know in android we can read an image into bitmap as fallows

```
img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_name);
```

Is there any way to read all those images in for loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Go to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987392/how-to-pass-images-into-arrayliststring-in-android/20987471#20987471](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987392/how-to-pass-images-into-arrayliststring-in-android/20987471#20987471)

Comment: I placed all those images in drawable-mdpi folder,and i try to access as below  

" File imgFile = new File("/res/drawable-mdpi/" + file_name); "

But it's not working,correct me if there there is any wrong in my path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO like this way

```
List<Bitmap> imgList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

        for ( int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++)
        {
            imgList.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getResources().getIdentifier("num" + i, "drawable", getPackageName()))); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a custom array which contains all the resource id of your image and using a for loop

for example:

```
int ids[] = new int[]{R.id.img1, R.id.img2};
for(int id : ids) {
    img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        try{
            Class drawable = R.drawable.class;
            Field f = drawable.getField("num" + i);
            int id = f.getInt(null);
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
        }catch(Exception ex){
        }
    }
```

But this is a bad way. You can use Assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

define a array of image-id like this

```
int[] ImgArr = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2....};
```

Then you can iterate like this:

```
for ( int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
 img = getResources().getDrawable(ImgArr [n]);
}
```